# Boas práticas para dados de características de produto que podem ser diferentes para cada item

Tags: modelagem, engenharia-de-software, arquitetura-de-software, ddd

Possuo diversos produtos e cada um tem suas devidas características, uns possuem peso, outros não, uns possuem taxa extra e outros não, etc. É uma boa prática criar uma nova tabela de parâmetros de produtos e guardar um JSON sobre cada característica individual de cada produto? Não sei outra forma de fazer a não ser assim.

Comment: Já pensou na possibilidade de usar um banco não relacional?

Comment: Então, não sei se compensa usar um banco inteiro não relacional apenas para resolver isso...

Comment: Você pode usar a relação a seu fazer e armazenar os dados em uma tabela separada, `produtos_parametros`, que possui uma chave estrangeira ao registro de produto, o nome e o valor do parâmetro, em uma relação 1:N. Se for o caso, você pode ter até outra coluna que indica o tipo do valor daquele parâmetro. Na tabela produtos você deixa apenas as informações que são comuns a todos.

Comment: @DaniloTiagoThaiSantos Alguma das respostas resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitar uma delas? Veja o [tour] como fazer isso, se ainda não o fez. Você ajudaria a comunidade identificando qual foi a melhor solução para você. Pode aceitar apenas uma delas. Mas pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo

Answer (score 3):

Na verdade já pensou que não só deve usar relacional como nem deve criar outra tabela? É assim que começa o mal uso do tal do NoSQL, as pessoas olham por uma poeirinha de problema e aí acham que a solução é usar uma coisa completamente diferente que ajuda nesse mínimo detalhe e ferra com todo o resto que te ajudava por usar o relacional.

E o AP está no caminho certo, enxergou uma solução óbvia que as pessoas não enxergam. Se esses dados são essencialmente descritivos e variam, o relacional tem uma solução simples, armazene isto como um dado descritivo. Olha que mágico! E com o detalhe de que alguns SGDBs até possuem mecanismos que facilitam isto e permitem indexação normalmente de foma simples (outros precisa de um esforço adicional). Não foi dito na pergunta que banco de dados está sendo usado, mas se é pra trocar que seja um relacional que ajude manipular bem esta situação e não deixar de lado todas vantagens do relacional por algo tão secundário. Mas mesmo que o DB usado não for ideal ainda dá para trabalhar bem com isto.

A solução está na pergunta, basta usar um JSON ou um BSON ou um JSONB ou um YAML, ou até XML (argh), ou seja lá o formato que quiser usar de chave e valor com as características específicas de cada produto em único documento, alguns já usam isto nativamente, outros serão tratados como `VARCHAR` e terá que criar umas funcoezinhas para manipular os dados de forma mais simples. O que você não pode fazer é querer criar campos para cada característica como vi algumas pessoas fazendo, aí fica horrível e a pessoa acaba achando mesmo que a única forma de resolver isto é ir para o NoSQL. Não, não é, basta usar o jeito *schemaless* que todo relacional permite em maior ou menor grau. Este não é um bom motivo para ir para NoSQL.

Quer por isto em outra tabela? Ok, pode, mas olhando por cima nem acho necessário e provavelmente inadequado, é uso errado do relacional (salvo eu ter entendido o problema errado). Faça se tiver um bom motivo. As pessoas tomam muitas decisões sem ter um bom motivo, por exemplo ir para um NoSQL, sendo que o único motivo que a pessoa tinha era que ela não sabe modelar bem o problema dela. Aí ela tem um modelo ruim e mecanismo inadequado.

O que as pessoas não entenderam é que dá pra fazer no relacional o mesmo que dá no modelo de documento. O modelo de documento só tem vantagem que ele pode escalar horizontalmente de forma mais simples (o relacional dá mais trabalho, mas dá também), enquanto que ele abre mão da consistência e integridade de dados tão importante para a maioria das aplicações (até por gerar duplicidade, que é difícil gerenciar). Em geral quem adota NoSQL costuma fazer a aplicação dar a consistência, o que é absurdamente mais difícil do que qualquer coisa que você faz no relacional.

Você pode achar que dá um pouco mais de trabalho ter que manipular esses dados no relacional, e isto é verdade, um pouco sim, mas no NoSQL tem tanta coisa que dá mais trabalho, só troca de problema. Não estou dizendo que chega em um ponto que o NoSQL não seja mais interessante, mas são raros casos. E também tem certos padrões que talvez o NoSQL não dê tanto trabalho assim, mas não são aplicações típicas. Em geral modelos de documento não normalizam dados e gerenciar dados não normalizados vai de difícil à insanidade (por isso tem tanto aplicativo que dá informações completamente *non sense*.

Existem alguns casos que fazer uma tabela de chave valor de forma relacional vale a pena, mas duvido que seja o caso. Existe momento que você deve abandonar o modelo relacional, mas não o RDBMS (SGDBR) que sabe trabalhar de forma híbrida. Quem não sabe ser híbrido é o NoSQL típico (conheço alguns NoSQL que sabem, mas não são os que as pessoas usam, irônico).

Resumindo:

- Não use NoSQL
- Não crie um monte de campos opcionais
- Não crie uma tabela de chave-valor (provavelmente)
- Crie um documento de características no seu produto ou tabela auxiliar dentro do seu relacional.

Só me deu medo a *tag* DDD na pergunta, outra coisa que as pessoas adotam sem ter um motivo claro que precise daquilo. Aí depois que a pessoa adota não tem como voltar atrás e tem que fazer de conta que está sendo bom.

Answer (score 1):

Eu diria que usar uma estrutura relacional nesse caso seria ruim, eu optaria por um banco orientado a documentos pois em uma mesma collection você poderia ter documentos com estruturas diferentes.

Exemplo Produto Televisão:

- Tv Sony 
  4k
  Smart
  55
- Tv Lg
  Full HD
  30

Perceba que a estrutura é diferente, a sony é smart e a Lg não.

No caso do banco relacional mesmo quando algum atributo não é preenchido na query ele trás o atributo vazio, no banco não relacional ele é capaz de trazes na mesma query documentos com estruturas diferentes deixando assim a leitura de dados bem mais rápida.